# How to plot a multilevel model treatment effect in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, model, mixed

I want to plot the Group-Time-Interaction of my multilevel model. I only managed to plot it without the multilevel structure. How can I include the nesting? Each patient was measured 3 times (before the treatment, mid, and after) on the same instrument. The patients were randomized to 2 groups (waitlist and treatment). 
This is my model:

```
m8 <- lmer(score ~ 1 + +time*Group +(1| subject), data = df2)
```

This is what I did:

```
score <- data %>%
  filter(!is.na(score)) %>%  
  group_by(ti, Gruppe, ar, ID) %>%
  summarise(Max_Height = max(score)) %>%  # Calculating max score
  ungroup() %>%  # Need to ungroup so that the pipe doesn't get confused
  group_by(ti, Gruppe, ar) %>%
  summarise(score = mean(Max_Height)) 
(basic_mm_scatter <- ggplot(score, aes(ti, score, colour = Gruppe)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme_bw() +stat_smooth(method = "lm",))
```

I would also love to include error bars. No idea how to though. Help is ver appreciated!!! Thanks so much!

Comment: It is hard for people to help without a reproducible example.

Comment: the `effects`, `emmeans`, `sjPlot` packages might also be worth investigating

Comment: thanks with effects I did reach my goals much easier!